# #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax. For the right syntax to use near 'â€“

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I am using a query to get the nearest locations from my database but I am getting this error

**My query**:

```
SELECT * , 3956 * 2 * ASIN( SQRT (
POWER(SIN((65.97029333 - abs(postLatitude)) * pi()/180 / 2),
2) + COS(65.97029333 * pi()/180 ) * COS(abs(postLatitude) *
pi()/180) * POWER(SIN((-18.53303333 – postLongitude) *
pi()/180 / 2), 2) )) as distance
FROM userpost
HAVING distance < 10
ORDER BY distance LIMIT 10;
```

**Error**:

```
 #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'â€“ postLongitude) *
pi()/180 / 2), 2) )) as distance
FROM userpost
having di' at line 4
```

Help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The character between `-18.53303333` and `postLongitude` is not an ASCII minus sign, it's an EN-dash, Unicode code point `342387`. Replace it with a normal minus sign.

Comment: thank you  for saving my precious time. Appreciate it :)